# listing all jpg files in dir and subdirs

Tags: php

How can I list all jpg files in a given directory and its subdirectories in PHP5 ?

I thought I could write a glob pattern for that but I can't figure it out.

thanx, b.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator) with a [filter](http://php.net/FilterIterator):

```
class ImagesFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    public function accept()
    {
        $file = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return preg_match('/\.jpe?g$/i', $file->getFilename());
    }
}

$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/var/images');
$it = new ImagesFilter($it);

foreach ($it as $file)
{
    // Use $file here...
}
```

`$file` is an [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/SplFileInfo) object.

Comment: You might want to add a `$` to your regex.

Answer (score 2):

without doing it for you. recursion is the answer here. a function that looks in a dir and gets a list of all files. filters out only th jpg's then calls its self if i finds any sub dirs

Answer (score 2):

Wish I had time to do more & test, but this could be used as a starting point: it should (untested) return an array containing all the jpg/jpeg files in the specified directory.

```
function load_jpgs($dir){
    $return = array();
    if(is_dir($dir)){
        if($handle = opendir($dir)){
            while(readdir($handle)){
                echo $file.'<hr>';
                if(preg_match('/\.jpg$/',$file) || preg_match('/\.jpeg$/',$file)){
                    $return[] = $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
            return $return;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: your while condition is really redundant. if it's true, you obviously won't need to *specify* it as !== false

Comment: Whoops, good catch. I repurposed some old code where that was necessary. Fixed. Thanks!